# Calculate $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^\pi \sin(x)^{1/n}|\log(x)| dx$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, lebesgue-measure

So we have been ask to calculate the limit:
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^\pi \sin(x)^{1/n}|\log(x)| dx$$
Since the function $\sin(x)^{1/n}|\log(x)|$ is dominated by $|\log(x)| $ $\forall 
 x\in(0,\pi) \forall n\in\mathbb N,$
the dominated convergence theorem applies and so:

$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^\pi \sin(x)^{1/n}|\log(x)|dx$$ $$=\int_0^\pi \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}  \sin(x)^{1/n}|\log(x)|dx$$$$=\int_0^\pi|\log(x)|dx$$
Is this right?

Comment: @b00nheT you sure about that?

Comment: It is right yes!

Comment: @b00n heT that was my main concern. Since it's the same area as $\int_{-\infty}^0 e^x dx$ and this integral it's well defined, I thought that $\int_0^1 log(x) dx$ would be too

Comment: @b00nheT yes it is integrable, the poster is correct

Comment: The DCT is applicable since $\int_0^\pi |\log(x)|\,dx=\int_0^\infty \xi_{[0,\pi]}(x)|\log(x)|\,dx<\infty$.

Comment: Of course it is. I was completely wrong. Sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

As I said a completely wrong thing in the comment, here is an answer.

You can indeed apply DCT on that interval as the primitive of $\log(x)$ is
$x(\log(x)-1)$. Now we do a case division to deal with the absolute value and see that the integral evaluates to
\begin{align}\int_0^\pi|\log(x)|dx&=-\int_0^1\log(x)dx+\int_1^\pi\log(x)dx\\ &=-x(\log(x)-1)\big|_0^1+x(\log(x)-1)\big|_1^\pi\\ &=2+\pi(\log(\pi)-1))<\infty\end{align}

So DCT is applicable and your reasoning applies