# Prove that I can switch limit and integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm stuck with this problem on Lebesgue Integration and measure theory (I'm a newbie in this subject). I have to do the following integral:

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(\sin{x} \right)^\frac{1}{n}\left| 
\log{x} \right|dx }
$$

I know, in order to prove that I can enter the limit operator into the integral one, it must satisfy the conditions of Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem, which are:

- The sequence of functions $f_n$ must be measurable
- The sequence of functions $f_n$ must converge a.e to a function $f$
- There must exist a function $g$ $\mu$-integrable such that $\forall\ n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, $|f_n|\le g$

Here is my attempt:

- To show that the sequence of $f_n=\left(\sin{x} \right)^\frac{1}{n}\left| 
  \log{x} \right|$ is measurable I define the domain $X = (0, \pi] $ for the $f_n$ and I try to apply that if a function $y$ is continuous in $X$ then it is measurable. Is this way correct?
- Such limit equals to  $f=\left| \log{x} \right| $, although I don't actually know if it is uniform or pointwise. Is it important?
- In the third one, can I take $g=f=\left| \log{x} \right|$ as the dominate function?

I believe I can swap Limit and integral operators, but cannot show it mathematically.
Any suggestions?

Thank you all

PD: I reckon this is not a duplicate question of [Calculate $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^\pi \sin(x)^{1/n}|\log(x)| dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2972357/calculate-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-int-0-pi-sinx1-n-logx-dx) because there is not showed formaly what i want. It doesn't matter that the function is the same, what matters to me is the theory behind

Comment: See the same question here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2972357/calculate-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-int-0-pi-sinx1-n-logx-dx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^\pi \sin(x)^{1/n}|\log(x)| dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2972357/calculate-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-int-0-pi-sinx1-n-logx-dx)

Comment: thanks, but then, how can I show that the $f_n$ are measurable by applying the definition of a measurable function? I mean, showing that $\{ x: f(x)>c   \}\in \mathcal{A}\ \forall \ c\in \mathbb{R}$.
That thing is not mentioned in that post

Comment: @Dani you can show for $\sin^{1/n}x$ by taking cases of $c$ . Your function is almost monotone look from 0 to pi/2 and from pi/2  to pi .